# tkinter python script crashes when opening from mac command line

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to make a small GUI in python (version 3.8.3) using tkinter. I wrote the whole script in the PyCharm IDE and I was able to run it without issue and still can. However trying to run it from the command line results in a crash and I get the following output:

> 2020-07-25 22:22:57.888 Python[69416:1640503] -[SDLApplication
> _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffcdd2ad590 2020-07-25 22:22:57.890 Python[69416:1640503] *** Terminating app due
> to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
> '-[SDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
> 0x7ffcdd2ad590'
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff378a7797 __exceptionPreprocess + 250  1   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x00007fff7073aa9e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
> 0x00007fff379269a6 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0  3
> CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3780bf30
> ***forwarding*** + 1427   4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3780b908 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   libtk8.6.dylib
> 0x000000010fd051f2 TkpInit + 408  6   libtk8.6.dylib
> 0x000000010fc74aac Initialize + 2454  7
> _tkinter.cpython-38-darwin.so       0x000000010fac8714 Tcl_AppInit + 84   8   _tkinter.cpython-38-darwin.so       0x000000010fac8032
> _tkinter_create + 1362    9   Python                              0x000000010f790e8f cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 175  10  Python
> 0x000000010f822c4c call_function + 444    11  Python
> 0x000000010f81faae _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678   12  Python
> 0x000000010f823a94 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804    13  Python
> 0x000000010f75504e _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270   14  Python
> 0x000000010f7543b7 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 247   15  Python
> 0x000000010f7559bf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143   16  Python
> 0x000000010f7abb21 slot_tp_init + 145     17  Python
> 0x000000010f7a6ff9 type_call + 297    18  Python
> 0x000000010f754565 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373     19  Python
> 0x000000010f822ca5 call_function + 533    20  Python
> 0x000000010f81faae _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678   21  Python
> 0x000000010f823a94 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804    22  Python
> 0x000000010f819584 PyEval_EvalCode + 100  23  Python
> 0x000000010f8690f0 PyRun_FileExFlags + 336    24  Python
> 0x000000010f8687e0 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 864  25  Python
> 0x000000010f885c6f Py_RunMain + 2159  26  Python
> 0x000000010f885faf pymain_main + 223  27  Python
> 0x000000010f8861ab Py_BytesMain + 43  28  libdyld.dylib
> 0x00007fff718d9cc9 start + 1  29  ???
> 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
> uncaught exception of type NSException Abort trap: 6

The script ran perfectly when being called from the command line on a Windows computer but for whatever reason I cant get it to run from the command line on my mac, but yet it works in the IDE...

I'll include the code below. I would appreciate any help I can get and if you need more information just ask

```
import tkinter as tk
import youtube_dl
from moviepy.editor import *
import shutil


BG = "#191970"
# midnight blue #191970


main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.title("Video Scraper")
main_window.geometry("850x690")
main_window.config(bg=BG)

frame = tk.Frame(main_window, bg="white")
frame.place(relx="0.1", rely="0.05", relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.9)

title = tk.Label(frame, text="Video Scraper")
title.config(font=("Verdana", 44))
title.pack(fill="x")

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Please enter the url(s) of the videos you would like to download so that there's "
                             "only 1 link per line\nAlso note that there can't be any spaces at the beginning or "
                             "end of the line", bg="pink")
label.pack()

text_area = tk.Text(frame, bg="#BBFFFF")
text_area.pack(fill="y", expand=True)

frame2 = tk.Frame(main_window, bg=BG)
frame2.place(relx="0.2", rely="0.95", relwidth=0.6, relheight=0.05)

var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(2)


def set_var1():
    var.set(1)


def set_var2():
    var.set(2)


audio_only = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text=".mp3", variable="var", value=1, command=set_var1)
vid_and_aud = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text=".mp4", variable="var", value=2, command=set_var2)
audio_only.pack(side="left")
vid_and_aud.pack(side="left")


def get_text():
    text = text_area.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    broken_text = text.split("\n")
    links = []
    for item in broken_text:
        link = [item]
        links.append(link)
    audio_only.config(state="disabled")
    vid_and_aud.config(state="disabled")
    download_btn.config(state="disabled")
    download_videos(links, var.get())


def download_videos(url_links, download_format):
    counter = 0
    vid_info = []
    print(url_links)
    print(download_format)

    # Get video data for each link and put it into a list
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
        for link in url_links:
            meta = ydl.extract_info(link[0], download=False)
            vid_info.append(meta)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'mp4',
        'outtmpl': '%(title)s.mp4',
        'quiet': True,
        'noplaylist': True
    }

    while counter < len(url_links):
        filename = vid_info[counter]['title'] + ".mp4"
        print("\n\nDownloading --> " + filename)
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download(url_links[counter])
        print("Video Successfully Downloaded!")
        if download_format == 1:
            print("Converting Video(.mp4) to Audio(.mp3)...")
            video = VideoFileClip(filename)
            audio_file = filename.replace("mp4", "mp3")
            video.audio.write_audiofile(audio_file, logger=None)
            video.close()
            print("Video Successfully Converted!")
            print("Cleaning up...")
            # remove video file
            print("--> Removing Video(.mp4) File")
            os.remove(filename)
            # move audio
            print("--> Moving Audio to Audio(mp3) Folder")
            shutil.move(audio_file, "Audio(mp3)")
            print("--> Done")
            print("Completed " + str(counter + 1) + "/" + str(len(url_links)))
        else:
            shutil.move(filename, "Video(mp4)")
            print("Completed " + str(counter + 1) + "/" + str(len(url_links)))
        counter += 1


download_btn = tk.Button(frame2, text="Download!", command=get_text)
download_btn.pack(side="right")

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What output do you get on running following command in Terminal: `PYTHONVERBOSE=3 python your_script.py`. Replace `your_script.py` with the name of your file.

Comment: @isAif I got the same error at the end, and just briefly looking through it I didnt see anything too suspicious but I mean it came out to be like 11000 or so lines so I didnt look through all of it. Obviously wayyy too long for me to post here but I saved the output to a txt file if you would like to see it. Is there anything specific I should be looking for?

Comment: Just the line before `Abort trap: 6`. You will see the name of module causing the problem.

Comment: @isAif theres no difference from what I posted above. The line above Abort trap: 6 is -- 'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException'. However the last import call is -- 'import 'moviepy.editor' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f89d4bff9a0>'

Comment: Did you even find a solution for this?

Comment: @CigogneEveillée Unfortunately I did not :(